# Ionic ERROR [object object]

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic

Como puedo solucionar el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os dejo el codigo de mi proveedor:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WordpressProvider {

baseUrl:string ="http://mipagina.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/9159";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello WordpressProvider Provider');
  }

  recibirEventos(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }

}
```

El de mi home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WordpressProvider } from './../../providers/wordpress/wordpress';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

datos
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public http: HttpClient,
              public wordpress: WordpressProvider) {


    this.wordpress.recibirEventos().subscribe(data=>{
      this.datos = data;
      });

  }
}
```

y el del home.html

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of datos">
{{item.id}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: puedes desplegar que retorna this.datos = data;

Answer (score 0):

Habría que ver que tipo de dato está llegando a través de la petición get, que según el error no es un array u objeto iterable.
Ésto se puede solucionar haciendo un `console.log()`

```
this.wordpress.recibirEventos().subscribe(data=>{
  this.datos = data;
  console.log(data);
  });
```

o usando un programa mas especifico como puede ser el Postman que te permite gestionar todo tipo de consulta y su respuesta.

Para evitar errores es recomendable gestionar el tipo de variable que vas a asignar, en éste caso, a la variable this.datos que tranquilamente podría ser declarada

```
export class HomePage {

public datos: any[];
...
```

y si puedes ser más específico en el tipo de dato mucho mejor (en lugar del any) además de que va a ser publica (`public`) pues la usaremos en el HTML para poblar el listado. 
Ahora si queremos hacer el objeto iterable desde tu servicio/proveedor puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WordpressProvider {

baseUrl:string ="http://mipagina.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/9159";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello WordpressProvider Provider');
  }

  recibirEventos(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

Me estoy basando en los siguiente problemas reportados en [StackOverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660306/angular-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object) y [el foro de Ionic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-read-object-object-using-angular-2/92833/4) y espero que sea la solucion para tu problema

Comment: Tengo entendido que desde angular 4.3 ya no es necesario utilizar .map, ya que se implemento HttpClient que te devuelve el json. En todo caso a la hora de utilizar .map es necesario importar import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';. Respeto a lo que me dijiste he hecho un console.log(this.datos); y he visto que no tiene la propiedad symbol(symbol.itarator). No se si eso sea lo que me esta dando erros y en caso de ser eso tampoco tengo claro como solucionarlo.

Comment: no se si es mucha molestia, pero si pudieras editar el baseUrl y cambiar la pagina por mipagina (por ejemplo), es que se me paso el nombre. Un saludo

Comment: Podrías, entonces, dar referencia sobre que versión del framework estás usando? y claro ya lo edito.